# Make division use all available size in it's parent

Tags: html, css

In the code bellow the parent div's width will change dynamically. Left and right divisions have fixed width. I need middle division fill the remain space in the parent division. This way I think middle division's width should change dynamically according to it's parent div.

```
<body>
   <div id='parent' style='width:100%'>
      <div id='leftDiv' style='width:30px;float:left;'>left division</div>
      <div id='middleDiv' ***style='width:??;'***>middle division</div>
      <div id='rightDiv' style='width:30px;float:right;'>right division</div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Please note that I want to do this just with CSS, not js.

Comment: `width: calc(100% - 30px - 30px);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need of width for middleDiv, just add `float:right;` div to the first.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1qoozgm0/)**

Below is the solution:

```
<div id='parent' style='width:100%'>
      <div id='rightDiv' style='width:100px;float:right;background-color:red;'>right division</div>
      <div id='leftDiv' style='width:100px;float:left;background-color:green;'>left division</div>
      <div id='middleDiv' style='background-color:yellow;'>middle division</div>      
   </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

use like this

```
width: calc(100% - 60px);
```

left div 30px right div 30px = 60px
middle div width = 100% - 60px

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a good candidate for the [Media object](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2010/06/25/the-media-object-saves-hundreds-of-lines-of-code/)

```
.parent,
.middleDiv {
   overflow:hidden;
   _overflow:visible;
   zoom:1;
}

.leftDiv {
   float: left;
   width: 30px;
}

.rightDiv {
   float: right;
   width: 30px;
}
```